# "No emoji found" in Google Japanese Input

Tags: emoticons, google-japanese-input

I am using [Google Japanese Input](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.japanese) keyboard, and I often want to post a rare emoji such as  or .

The search bar looks like the perfect place to search for an emoji, but unfortunately it fails every time:
[image]

It fails even on the simplest requests, such as "smile" or "sad".
It does not work in Japanese either:

[image]

I have changed phones, and changed OS (Nexus default, CyanogenMod, LineageOS, Samsung default) many times: The problem has always been present. So I guess it is not a bug, but rather a problem of me not using it correctly.

How to use that feature correctly?

Comment: Note that Gboard with Japanese keyboard can search emoticon with katakana and kanji, but still not with English (it only interprets emoticon in current keyboard language)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer 10 minutes after posting the question, that's silly.

The trick is, you must search in [hiragana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana). Even if your locale is English (like in my case).

For instance, search for `ねこ` instead of `cat` or `猫`:

[image: Google Japanese Input - emoji search]

Most users type the hiragana before getting the kanji anyway, so it kind of makes sense if you think about it afterwards.